# 'reader.result' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047) error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a typescript + react fileinput component. However I'm getting typescript error 'Object is possibly null'. I have googled but couldn't find solution for this problem. How can I fix this problem without disabling typescript null check

The zod schema set up as fileone: z.string().refine(Base64.isValid).

```
const SignupForm = ({ onSubmit }: { onSubmit: (values: any) => void }) => {
    const [state] = useState<string>();
    const {
        formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    } = useForm<TsformSchema>({ resolver: zodResolver(formSchema) });
    const form = useForm<TsformSchema>({ resolver: zodResolver(formSchema) });

    const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
        maxFiles: 1,
        accept: {
            "image/*": [],
        },
        onDrop(acceptedFiles, fileRejections, event) {
            if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
                
                const reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = () => {
                    console.log("file_upload");
                    // convert file to base64 String
                    const base64String = reader.result
                        .replace("data:", "")
                        .replace(/^.+,/, "");
                    // // store file
                    // localStorage.setItem("wallpaper", base64String);
                    // // display image
                    // document.body.style.background = `url(data:image/png;base64,${base64String})`;
                    form.setValue("fileone", base64String);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(acceptedFiles[0]);
                //

                form.clearErrors("fileone");
            } else {
                form.setError("fileone", {
                    message: "test error message",
                });
            }
            console.log(acceptedFiles.length > 0);
        },
    });
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: Initialize `acceptedFiles` with an empty array to ensure it's never undefined. like this: `const { acceptedFiles = [], getRootProps, isDragActive }`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `if(!reader.result) return;`
You will check if the result is null - you will stop function execution, but if it's not null execution will continue.

```
 reader.onload = () => {
                console.log("file_upload");
                // convert file to base64 String
                if(!reader.result) return;
                const base64String = reader.result
                    .replace("data:", "")
                    .replace(/^.+,/, "");
                // // store file
                // localStorage.setItem("wallpaper", base64String);
                // // display image
                // document.body.style.background = `url(data:image/png;base64,${base64String})`;
                form.setValue("fileone", base64String);
            };
```